# I want to disable buttons when nothing is selected in the list boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi Experts I'm new to jQuery. I have enabled the "Add category" button if any three values(one value per each box) are selected from the above three boxes. I want to enable the "Remove Category" & "Save Categories" button only if there is any values in the fourth box But, My code is not working for this.

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();


$('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
  var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
  var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
  var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
  if (one && two && three) {
    $("#add-category").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#add-category").prop("disabled", true);
  }

});

$('#selected-lst-values').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});

$('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});
$('#remove-category').click(function() { // check change here
  var select = document.getElementById('selected-lst-values');

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
  }
    if ($('#selected-lst-values').val()) {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", true);
  }



});
$('#selected-lst-values>option').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $('#mnage-category-savebtn').attr({
      disabled: disabled
    });

  } else {
    $('#mnage-category-savebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled>
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled>
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button id='save-categories' class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button" disabled><strong>Save Categories</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#selected-lst-values').val() != null) {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have update this :

```
if (one && two && three) {
    $("#add-category").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#remove-category").prop("disabled",false);
  }
```

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();


$('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
  var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
  var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
  var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
  if (one && two && three) {
    $("#add-category").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#add-category").prop("disabled", true);
  }

});

$('#selected-lst-values').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});

$('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});
$('#remove-category').click(function() { // check change here
  var select = document.getElementById('selected-lst-values');

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
  }
    if ($('#selected-lst-values').val()) {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", true);
  }



});
$('#selected-lst-values>option').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $('#mnage-category-savebtn').prop('disabled',true)

  } else {
    $('#mnage-category-savebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled>
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled>
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button id='save-categories' class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button" disabled><strong>Save Categories</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Bhansa :) But, I want to enable these two buttons(Remove Category & Save Categories) only if there are any values in the fourth list box otherwise shouldn't. i.e After selecting the values we will click "Add category" So, some values will be there in fourth box. Now the "Remove Category & Save Categories" buttons should enabled otherwise it should disabled.

Comment: Thank you :) But, The Remove Category & Save Categories buttons enabling only if  i click any values in the fourth list box.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can bind to event or use SetInterval method of JQuery.
(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

once you set interval it will execute every 3 seconds

```
setInterval(function(){  
    if ($('#selected-lst-values').val!=null) {
      $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", false);
    } 
    else {
      $('#remove-category').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#save-categories').prop("disabled", true);
    } }, 3000);
```